# construction of ES256KSigner throws mis-match private key length

Tags: digital-signature, private-key, jwk, secp256k1, decentralized-identity

I tried to build a siger to sign a verifiable credential using jwt format. But the construct of ES256KSigner fails `Invalid private key format. Expecting 32 bytes, but got 43`. I am not familar with cryption, and only guess there is some wrong understanding for hte `d`  in the `privateJwk`. Thanks if you can help correct me.

My sample code:

```
import { anchor, DID, generateKeyPair } from '@decentralized-identity/ion-tools';
import { ES256KSigner, hexToBytes } from 'did-jwt';
  let authKeys = await generateKeyPair();
  console.log("generate key: ", authKeys)
   //The d field in the privaeteJwk is private key and used for signer construction.
  let signer = ES256KSigner(authKeys.privateJwk.d)
```

And the output:

```
generate key:  {
  publicJwk: {
    kty: 'EC',
    crv: 'secp256k1',
    x: 'AgykbSMim_qMMlo0Lh2DucKZ3XwpvGh6qv4BXQo1lxE',
    y: 'X_7mp4aTLjYQuxdSgEpb-3RtCgLeevp6FG34HwC5XjQ'
  },
  privateJwk: {
    kty: 'EC',
    crv: 'secp256k1',
    x: 'AgykbSMim_qMMlo0Lh2DucKZ3XwpvGh6qv4BXQo1lxE',
    y: 'X_7mp4aTLjYQuxdSgEpb-3RtCgLeevp6FG34HwC5XjQ',
    d: 'tcGhsoByPlNppNLQxr_hFNAR7lGhB1JW_SFo4rxTZpo'
  }
}
file:///work/did/did_demo/node_modules/did-jwt/lib/index.module.js:184
    throw new Error(`bad_key: Invalid private key format. Expecting 32 bytes, but got ${privateKeyBytes.length}`);
          ^

Error: bad_key: Invalid private key format. Expecting 32 bytes, but got 43
    at ES256KSigner (file:///work/did/did_demo/node_modules/did-jwt/lib/index.module.js:184:11)
    at file:///work/did/did_demo/issuer.js:13:16
```

The version information:

```
   "@decentralized-identity/ion-tools": "^1.0.7",
    "did-jwt": "^7.2.2",
    "did-jwt-vc": "^3.2.3",
    "elliptic": "^6.5.4",
    "express": "^4.18.2"
```

After checking `generateKeypair` in https://github.com/decentralized-identity/ion-tools/blob/main/src/utils.js and conform it uses `secp256k1`
[image: Code to generate key]

And the construction of ES256KSigner from the link https://github.com/decentralized-identity/did-jwt/blob/master/docs/guides/index.md#signer-functions

=================Workaround===========

After checking the source code further, I findally use the Workaround like this:

```
import { base64url } from 'multiformats/bases/base64';
let privateKey = base64url.baseDecode(this.authnKeys.privateJwk.d);
let signer = ES256KSigner(privateKey)
```

This is caused by some inconsistence as talked by Topaco.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the JWK the raw private key (`d`) is Base64url encoded, so your code should work, since according to the [documentation for version 7.2.2](https://github.com/decentralized-identity/did-jwt/blob/7.2.2/docs/guides/index.md#es256ksigner) the key can also be passed Base64url encoded to `ES256KSigner()`.

Unfortunately, the documentation is not consistent with the [code for version 7.2.2](https://github.com/decentralized-identity/did-jwt/blob/7.2.2/src/signers/ES256KSigner.ts#L21), which states that the key can only be passed as a `Uint8Array`. This leads to the [exception](https://github.com/decentralized-identity/did-jwt/blob/7.2.2/src/signers/ES256KSigner.ts#L24), which is thrown directly in `ES256KSigner()`, after a failed length check of the key.

Note that in earlier versions it was indeed possible to pass a Base64url encoded key (e.g. in [version 5.12.4](https://github.com/decentralized-identity/did-jwt/blob/5.12.4/src/signers/ES256KSigner.ts#L24)), but this has been changed as of [version 6.0.0](https://github.com/decentralized-identity/did-jwt/blob/6.0.0/src/signers/ES256KSigner.ts#L24). Apparently, the documentation was simply not adapted in this process.

The Base64url decoding required in version 7.2.2 is supported with the helper function [`base64ToBytes()`](https://github.com/decentralized-identity/did-jwt/blob/7.2.2/src/util.ts#L38):

```js
let signer = ES256KSigner(base64ToBytes(authKeys.privateJwk.d));
```

With this fix the key import works.